# Composer/WordPress : wp-content directory should or should not be committed

Tags: php, wordpress, git, dependencies, composer-php

So I recently started to use Composer with WordPress based on [this](https://davidwinter.me/install-and-manage-wordpress-with-composer/) tutorial.

This is my `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "wordpress",
                "type": "webroot",
                "version": "4.3",
                "dist": {
                    "type": "zip",
                    "url": "https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/archive/4.3.zip"
                },
                "require" : {
                    "fancyguy/webroot-installer": "1.0.0"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "wordpress": "4.*",
        "fancyguy/webroot-installer": "1.0.0"
    },
    "extra": {
        "webroot-dir": "public/wp",
        "webroot-package": "wordpress"
    }
}
```

It worked fine, I got this folder structure:

[image]

As it was mentioned in the tutorial, I copied `index.php`, `wp-config.php` and the `wp-content` directory outside the `wp` directory and replaced the paths.

Everything worked perfect until this point:

> *Regarding housekeeping with your source code management tool. You’d want to ignore the composer.phar file and public/wp directory.
>   Everything else can be committed and pushed.*

So it seems like that besides the `public/wp` folder, everything can be committed and pushed. (including wp-content folder)

Here is the thing that I don't understand. We must commit/push the `wp-content` directory because it has a different location that it use to have, but in the same time this `wp-content` folder contains the `plugins` and `themes` folder in which our plugins and themes will be added using composer which should not be committed/pushed right ?.

The plugins and themes will be added on the development enviroment also using composer, so we must not commit them, but they are in the `wp-content` directory which should be committed ?

In [another](https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/composer-wordpress/git-file-system-layout/#gitignore-file) similar tutorial the `wp-content` is set into the `.gitignore` file, meaning that it should not be commited/pushed. But If it's like this, who will move (and how) the `wp-content` outside `wp` directory on the development enviroment.

Can somebody clarify this aspect please?

Comment: I commit wp-content and my main theme and exclude everything else with .gitignore - I then use composer to bring in all the plugins I need via http://wpackagist.org/ - so your git contains wp-content but only the theme and nothing else (you can bring the theme in as well with composer if you want but for me thats like having two repos for one site)

Answer (score 2):

It's great that you have `wp-content` split out into a separate directory.

Personally I only commit items in `wp-content` that are part of the current project. Another way to think of this is commit anything *not* added with Composer.

For example, you could be working on a site with a parent theme, which you are pulling in with Composer and will leave unmodified, and a child theme, which you are making changes to.

In this example the child theme should be committed and the parent theme ignored since you are only changing code in the child theme.

The `.gitignore` file would look like this:

```
# Ignore everything in wp-content
wp-content/*

# Do not ignore the themes directory. This is needed to add the child theme (below)
!wp-content/themes

# Ignore all of the themes directory contents, including the parent theme
wp-content/themes/*

# Do not ignore the child theme
!wp-content/themes/child-theme/
```

I typically do the same thing with plugins as well. Any plugins pulled in by Composer are ignored but plugins specific to the current project, that you will not use elsewhere, are committed.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is: anything generated should not be versioned.

> who will move (and how) the `wp-content` outside `wp` directory on the development environment.

That is a deployment issue, part of release management.
That means a post-receive hook on the server side would be in charge of generating the right content based on the newly pushed sources, and move/copy the `wp-content` folder, once its content has been refreshed.

The general point is: one generally differentiates versioning from deployment. Moving content is something done at deployment, during release management, for instance by a hook which will move the right resources to the right place.

Comment: What do you mean by generated, and what you you mean by versioned. Can you explain more please because I don't understand?

Comment: @paulalexandru "generated" means you can call a command which will generates all or some of the contents in wp-content. "versioned" means added tou source control (git add, git commit)

Comment: Yes but wp-content is not generated this means that I should commit it ? because the folders which are inside are generated.

Comment: @paulalexandru you can add and commit only what is not generated in `wp-content`, but exclude (declared in `.gitignore`) what is generated in `wp_content`.

Comment: So should I commit the wp-content directory it's self? And what do you mean by That means a post-receive hook on the server side would be in charge of generating the right content based on the newly pushed sources, and move/copy the wp-content folder, once its content has been refreshed. ?

Comment: @paulalexandru git does not commit folder, only folder *content* (ie files). if wp-content includes files that are *not* generated, those files should be versioned.

Comment: @paulalexandru the post-receive hook is a server-side hook which will be triggered by any push. It can then make any post-receive process you want in order to generate and deploy the missing files.

Comment: Well wp-content contains from the begining (wordpress instalation with composer) themes folder, plugins folder and and index.php this means that I should add this into the .gitignore file?

Comment: @paulalexandru if those are already present on the server (as part of the installation of wp itself there) then yes. Only what you create or modify should be versioned, and then, on the server side, copied over the destination folder when pushed.

Comment: So you said that only what I modify should be versioned. Well I modified that wp-content path, I moved is outside the wp content. So how should I version this? since you said we can't commit folders? only the content from inside folders? Because inside the wp-content we have files which were generated. So I still don't understand. Can you be more clear ? mabey update the answer.

Comment: @paulalexandru my point is: one generally differentiates versioning from deployment. Moving content is something done at deployment, during release management, for instance by a hook which will move the right resources to the right place.

Comment: As you can see in my question in the second tutorial the wp-content directory is set into the .gitignore file, this means we should not commit thi folder. But if we don't commit , it means on the development enviroment this folder will be still inside wp folder.

Comment: @paulalexandru I have seen the tutorial, and maintain my point about not mixing versioning and deployment.

Comment: Well I don't have any problem on my localhost, the problem comes when I try to put the website on DEV. And after all this discussions, I still don't know what I have to do, to make it right.